# Launch app using shake gesture

Tags: ios, iphone

Is there a way to launch an app by shaking the iPhone?
I want my app to launch when the user shakes their iPhone (a certain number of shakes).

Comment: By tapping on the app icon. It's easier without shaking the phone though.

Comment: it's for the safety of women in an emergency situation

Comment: There is no such way. The device has number of apps installed. OS doesn't recognise this gesture to open an app or any other app for that matter.

Comment: Your app is sandboxed.. you cant communicate like that from OS layer...

Comment: What if 50 other also want this? What is an OS to do? Launch all? Take a pick?

Comment: iOS already has an sos capability that can be triggered by clicking the side button 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

I believe thats not possible.
Apple can deal with this on its own end by OS.
What if the device gets shaken by accident? You've then got false alarms to deal with.